# Get values stdClass Object PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, stdclass

stdClass source http://zerrax.fr/b/example.php

```
$response->torrents[0]->[28]; ??
$response->torrents[0]->[0]; ??
```

Comment: who get data 0 and 28 ( torrents -> 0 )

Comment: Can you print "<pre>"; print_r(array); print"</pre>"; It would make it easily readable plz.

Comment: soory im noob is my first php project i dont understand

Comment: on example.php when u display your object - <pre> tag will preformat your text so you'll able to read easily your array.

Comment: What is the question. What are you trying to do and what happens?

Comment: Is it selecting from the 2d array that is the issue? `$response->torrents[0][28]` (without the arrow) should suffice.

Comment: not work 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in /home/ceqxizbx/public_html/b/example.php on line 17

Answer (score 1):

Access object keys using {} - allows you to encapsulate improper characters in object keys.

```
$response->torrents->{0}->{0};
```

In Your case you have arrays in torrents and then array within.
so that you have to access it next way:

```
$response->torrents[0][0];
```

Comment: or  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in /home/ceqxizbx/public_html/b/example.php on line 17

Comment: Post part of code retrieving, i will fix it for you :)

Comment: Check your previous line. PHP has pretty descriptive errors. You have not closed something. it says that expect " ) " to be there, but found $response variable. close the statement/command before.

Comment: <?php
require_once 'WebUIAPI.php';

// Construct a new API Object
// The URL must include the "gui" part
$webApi = new WebUIAPI("http://zerrax.ddns.net:8080/gui/");

// Set the username and password
$webApi->setLoginCredentials("0", "0");

// This call complies with the recent CSRF protection scheme
$webApi->fetchToken();

// Pass the parameters as array
$response = $webApi->callApi(array(
    "list" => 0
 $response->torrents->{0}->{0};
));
var_dump($response);
?>

Comment: $response = $webApi->callApi(array( "list" => 0 $response->torrents[0][0]));

Comment: :(
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in /home/ceqxizbx/public_html/b/example.php on line 17

Comment: i have fixed the part of code. Can you copy/past it? :-/

Comment: whole code.
<?php require_once 'WebUIAPI.php'; // Construct a new API Object 
// The URL must include the "gui" part 
$webApi = new WebUIAPI("zerrax.ddns.net:8080/gui/"); // Set the username and password 
$webApi->setLoginCredentials("0", "0"); 
// This call complies with the recent CSRF protection scheme 
$webApi->fetchToken(); // Pass the parameters as array 
$response = $webApi->callApi(array( "list" => 0 $response->torrents->[0][28])); 
var_dump($response); ?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ')' in /home/ceqxizbx/public_html/b/example.php on line 18

Comment: $webApi->callApi(array( "list" => $response->torrents->[0][28])); // is it supposed to work? )

Comment: no work Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in

Comment: it is me str class not valid ?

Comment: it is definitely you! you have a typo, php clearly states it for you!